# Dax filtering expressions, last date of every day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to graph data from a global table that contains information about inventory.

The table has a schema of (inventory amount, inventory sales, date, time, store)

Challenge is: every store logs 4-5 rows every day about inventory and sales and I have 4 stores.

My goal is to filter this table into a new table that includes only the last inventory amount and inventory sales of every day for every store.

Below is my input table:

[image: input table]

I'd like to generate an output like below. Note that only the second entry for store 600 on 9/2 is kept.

[image: output table]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried some filtering expressions but none worked worked for me.
enter image description here

[Update]:
So I tried the example from the answer below and I got this:

"Wednesday september 4th 2019, cell: 1new sill-fender cell3" is showing 18023; it should only show 1386

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would suggest doing this in M. It's a bit more verbose, but I think much clearer in what's happening. I've got a solution in M and in DAX below. For either solution, the approach is exactly the same:

1. Build a helper structure of (Store, Date, MaxTime) which is made of unique pairs of (Store, Date) and has the latest time that exists for that pair.
2. Filter the input table by the values in this helper table.

M solution first:

```
// Input - query with raw data - no work here:
let
    Source = #table(
        {"inventory amount", "Sale in dollar", "date", "time", "store"},
        {
            {54, 100, "2019-09-03", "09:55:00", 500},
            {52, 200, "2019-09-04", "10:34:00", 500},
            {49, 300, "2019-09-05", "09:43:00", 500},
            {112, 200, "2019-09-02", "13:13:00", 600},
            {111, 100, "2019-09-02", "13:19:00", 600},
            {109, 200, "2019-09-03", "15:25:00", 600}
        }
    ),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"inventory amount", Int64.Type}, {"Sale in dollar", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}, {"time", type time}, {"store", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

// StoreDateMaxTime - this is our helper table. This is set not to load into the
// model, just used in PQ for data processing.
let
    Source = Input,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"date", "store"}, {{"MaxTime", each List.Max([time]), type time}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

// Output - our final table
let
    Source = Input,
    #"Merged Queries" =
        Table.NestedJoin(
            Source, {"store", "date", "time"},
            StoreDateMaxTime, {"store", "date", "MaxTime"},
            "HelperDedupe",
            JoinKind.Inner),
    // Note that we join above, but don't use the results of the join in any way
    // we only care about the filtering semantic of an inner join.
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"HelperDedupe"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the DAX version doing exactly the same thing:

```
Output2 = 
VAR StoreDateMaxTime =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GROUPBY (
            'Input',
            'Input'[store],
            'Input'[date]
        ),
        "MaxTime", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Input'[time] ) )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Input',
        TREATAS ( StoreDateMaxTime, 'Input'[store], 'Input'[date], 'Input'[time] )
    )
```

Note that you could also just load the full input table and define a measure as follows that will return the last inventory record:

```
FinalInventoryAmount = 
VAR LastStoreDateTimes =
    GENERATE(
        VALUES ( 'Input'[store] ),
        CALCULATETABLE (
            TOPN (
                1,
                GROUPBY (
                    'Input',
                    'Input'[date],
                    'Input'[time]
                ),
                'Input'[date], DESC,
                'Input'[time], DESC
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Input'[inventory amount] ),
        TREATAS ( LastStoreDateTimes, 'Input'[store], 'Input'[date], 'Input'[time] )
    )
```

This measure should look fairly similar to the pattern for making the table. We're again doing a largely similar operation. But to make it work well with filtering and totals, we need to do something slightly different:

1. Start with only the stores in context: `VALUES ( 'Input'[Store] )`
2. Find for each store its latest ('Input'[Date], 'Input'[Time]) pair  (the second arg to `GENERATE`)
3. Use those values from (2) to filter the fact table and only consider the latest row per store (the `CALCULATE).

You'll see that at the grand total level, this is returning 158, which is the last value for store 500 (the 49 from 9/5) and the last value for store 600 (the 109 from 9/3) to get `49 + 109 = 158`.

Here's a visual using the measure:
[image: visual using measure]

**Edit:** explaining more about how the measure works.

Here is a cross-tab (a Matrix visual), with date and time on the rows, and the store id on the columns.

[image: cross tab for measure with date, time, and store]

Let's walk through this. On 9/2, there are no records for store 500. There are two records for store 600. We can see the individual times of those. The later is 111 at 13:19. You can see that the total for store 600 on 9/2 is the later amount, 111. The total for 9/2, across all stores is 111, the latest amount for store 600.

On 9/3, there is one record for store 500: 54 at 09:55. There is also a single record for store 600: 109 at 15:25. We can see these individual transactions at the time level. At the date subtotal, we see the amount for store 500 and 600 next to one another. The total column for 9/3 shows the addition of `54 + 109 = 163`, which is the latest amount for each store added together for a total across all stores.

9/4 and 9/5 are boring, each with only a single transaction for store 500.

The Total row shows values for each store and a grand total in the total column.
The total for a store is the last value for that store. For store 500, this is 49, from 9/5 at 09:43. For store 600, this is 109, from 9/3 at 15:25. The grand total (total row, total column) is these two values - the latest from each store - added together: `49 + 109 = 158`.

The totals only consider one value from each store - whatever the latest one is in context.

**Edit2:** for values that have multiple records at the same instant. Updating the measure only, but it should be obvious how to include the same value for the M and DAX table versions.

```
FinalInventoryAmount v2
VAR LastStoreDateTimes =
    GENERATE(
        VALUES ( 'Input'[store] ),
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SAMPLE ( // SAMPLE will ignore ties for those identical rows
                1,
                GROUPBY (
                    'Input',
                    'Input'[date],
                    'Input'[time],
                    'Input'[inventory amount]
                ),
                'Input'[date], DESC,
                'Input'[time], DESC,
                'Input'[inventory amount], ASC // make sure we're getting the min
                                               // amount value.
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Input'[inventory amount] ),
        // and below is the other difference
        TREATAS (
            LastStoreDateTimes,
            'Input'[store],
            'Input'[date],
            'Input'[time],
            'Input'[inventory amount] // we're also only including rows that tie
                                      // on the min amount here.
        )
    )
```

If you don't care about totaling behavior, you could also just replace the `SUM` with a `MIN` to get the smallest amount at a (store, date, time) tuple.

Comment: So in the original table, I created the measure "FinalInventoryAmount" and then tried to graph the table.. "FinalInventoryAmount" value is summing all the values for one date of inventory and displaying that instead of the last value of each date.

Comment: Please share the layout of your visual - either a screengrab like mine that shows the visual and all the fields added to it and their sources, or list these out as "'Table'[Column] in Values field well". If you made any modifications at all from the code posted, please identify these as well. As you can see in the screenshot, it is working with a table visual based on an input table that is exactly what you have shared in your post. Feel free to edit your original question by adding these details of the items you're trying.

Comment: I've added further explanation of the measure in my answer. As I said, you can edit your original question with extra detail.

Comment: I have included some pictures and update in my question.

Comment: Note that you have 13 records with the same date and time. As I explained, the measure is grabbing the latest date and time. It is not summing all values for the date. It is summing all values for the latest date-time. There are 13 records for the latest date and time. It should be pretty obvious how to extend the measure to also sort by the literal value, but I'll update the answer to cover that.

Comment: I see. What can I do to grab only one to protect against such mistake of logging twice?

Comment: I was able to change it to min like you suggested and its showing a single value now, however this has limitations for example if the value increases i will still show the min.. another problem i noticed is that I cant see the times under the dates in the pivot table like you have. I attached a picture in my question showing the date in the pivot table. I also noticed my date doesn't have a hierarchy in my table, dont know if this is the cause. thanks a lot.

Comment: It will only show the min at a specific (date, time). If there is a new record with a later date and time, that will be the value returned, regardless of if it is higher or lower than previous. `MIN` is only changing what happens when there are many transactions for the same instant - you need to pick a way to handle many records at the same instant. `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, and `AVERAGE` all make sense to me, depending on what you need. You need to [drill down your matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual#using-drill-down-with-the-matrix-visual).